# How to remove useless data from firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to go through each user and if they don't meet a certain criteria (for example lastSeenDate being 6 years ago, delete them
however,when i run

```
final userList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots()
```

I only get the current logged in user.

why is that and how do i fix this? how else can we run scripts to refactor data if we can't access it?

I only get the selected one (aka the logged in one)

[image]

Comment: Can you share the image of users collection

Comment: Also: can you show a bit more code of what you do with `userList`, especially how you process the data in there (preferably with simple `print` statement) and how that leads you to determine there's only one document?

Comment: Please share the code - what do you do to userList after fetching?

Comment: i'm just printing the username and length of list. it's only 1. the logged in user

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the collection users throws a map of lists. instead of just a list like the other collections. I have no idea why...

solved the issue like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().forEach((element) {
  element.docs.forEach((element) {
   element.id, element.reference);
    if(element.data()['thingtocheck'] == null {
      element.reference.delete();
    }
  });
});
```